# how to collect event logs from cloud without deploying agents?

Tags: networking

I have been researching on the concept of how event logs are collected from cloud based applications like dropbox without deploying agents...i haven't found any clear explanation based on this...it would be grateful if someone could explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad topic and can be very confusing because everyone logs differently, so while i cannot answer the question definitively, I can hopefully help you along.

A good heuristic is to see if the cloud service supports one of the oldest logging standard, Syslog. Typically if they do, you will not need to deploy an agent, but configure log forwarding and listen for messages on Linux server you control (which already has a logging service running though it might need additional configuration). Also if the cloud service has a Syslog service running on the remote service, you potentially can use that service to forward logs to your Syslog server.

The mechanism used for transportation should be TLS because logs can unknowingly contain very sensitive data (Twitter just recently put out a security warning concerning this). You can see how to configure a Linux Syslog server with TLS [here](https://www.linux.com/blog/tls-encryption-and-mutual-authentication-using-syslog-ng-open-source-edition)